# How can I make selecting highest number more compact with python?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, optimization, coding-style

I have this code where I have an array of sizes (i,j) and for each of the j variables, I want to select the highest out of the I variables.

For example, I have array [[2,5,1][12,4,6],[1,7,8],[2,4,5]] and I want to get the highest number out of each of the inner arrays so it should return: [5,12,8,5]

I have the following code which works fine, however, it's a bit messy and hard to read so my question is can I make it more compact?

Here is the code I have:

```
high_net_profit = list()
for i in range(len(self.accum_profit[0])):
    high_value = 0
    for j in range((len(self.accum_profit))):
        if j == 0:
            high_value = self.accum_profit[j][i]
        else:
            if self.accum_profit[j][i] > high_value: high_value = self.accum_profit[j][i]
    high_net_profit.append(high_value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [[2, 5, 1], [12, 4, 6], [1, 7, 8], [2, 4, 5]]

out = [max(l) for l in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[5, 12, 8, 5]
```

---

Or:

```py
out = [*map(max, lst)]
print(out)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of this if the array was transposed? e.g. from your example [[2,12,1,2],[5,4,7,4],[1,6,8,5]] and I wanted the result of [12,7,8]

Comment: @HubertRzeminski In my example, I iterate over sublists `[[2,12,1,2],[5,4,7,4],[1,6,8,5]]` and for each sublist I find maximum with `max()` function. So `12` for `[2,12,1,2]`, `7` for `[5,4,7,4]` and `8` for `[1, 6, 8, 5]`. So the result is `[12, 7, 8]`

Comment: @HubertRzeminski - `[max(l[i] for l in lst) for i in range(len(lst[0]))]`.

Answer (score 2):

```py
s =  [[2,5,1][12,4,6],[1,7,8],[2,4,5]]
```

If you just need iterable object:

```py
x = map(max, s)
```

If you need a list, then wrap into `list`:

```py
x = list(map(max, s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using numpy. [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) is a very useful library when working with numbers:

```
import numpy as np

l_in = [[2, 5, 1], [12, 4, 6], [1, 7, 8], [2, 4, 5]]

# out = [max(l) for l in l_in]  # can also be used
out = list(np.max(l_in, axis=1))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[5, 12, 8, 5]
```